Locked out of updating Amplify App v5 Js. cannot login
I have a Amplify V5 app that is running quite smooth. Currently using DDB, Functions etc.
The App is based on Next JS 14 with SSR and is hosted on Amplify too
I have been updating the app regaulary (Front End Side of it) and it is in prod

Recently i wanted to add a new Model to my GraphQL API. And i tried to amplify push it i get into this issue where now the app asks to verify myself via Amplify Studio.
When i try and log into the studio it doent accept the username/password. even though the user/pass is correct and is from the Password Manager.
When i forget password i get no new email for Password
When i try to login with AWS Account it also doesnt work


Forums online suggest to Delete and Recreate the Stuido. But can even do that.
   {
  "name": "qaes-next",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "author": "Hani Q",
  "email": "hanan.ilyas@gmail.com",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "pre-commit": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^5.3.4",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.6.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.9.1",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.9.1",
    "@types/node": "20.3.3",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.4",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "^3.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "maplibre-gl": "^4.1.0",
    "next": "^14.2.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.6",
    "recharts": "^2.7.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^5.5.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-generator": "^6.9.1",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/d3-scale-chromatic": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.6",
    "aws-crt": "^1.15.22",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.8",
    "husky": "^8.0.3"
  }
}


Well, I think the user password had expired. Logged into the Console. Looked at the Cognito User Pool used by the Amplify Studio. Just reset the users password via aws cli. and i set a new permanent pass and logged back into Studio
